# jslint.js download link

Tags: javascript, jslint

Can't find download link for jslint.js from http://www.jslint.com/.
I have downloaded http://jslint.com/webjslint.js, but it doesn't work well 
Can anyone give me correct url to download it ?

Comment: I was wondering about the exact same thing. The JSLint website is surprisingly crappy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Douglas Crockfords (author) Github:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint